# Balzano intermediate theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Im asked to show there is some $c$ where $f(c) = g(c)$ if $f(x),g(x)$ are contained within $[0,1]$ and $f(0)<g(0)$ and $g(1) < f(1)$ and they are continuous. It's pretty obvious that they intersect but I don't know how to prove it without using the assumption that they intersect. Balzano intermediate theorem i've been trying to use.

Maybe I can assume they intersect at c then subtract $b=f(c)=g(c)$ from the functions at 0 and 1. So they will both cross the x axis. Can I use this to say that they do intersect at $b$

Comment: I think you can check an answer as correct, even if it is just a hint, given that the hint is the crucial part of the question.

Comment: $f(0)<g(0)$ and $g(1)<f(1)$ => $f(0)-g(0)<0$ and $f(1)-g(1)>0$ take $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ by IVT there exists $c$ such that $h(c)=0 => f(c)=g(c)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: consider the difference $f-g$ on this interval and look at the signs $f(0)-g(0)$ and $f(1)-g(1)$.

Comment: Got it, thank you will post proof in a second

Answer (score 0):

You just need to introduce the following function

$$h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$$

and observe that

$$h(0)h(1)<0$$

will hold and also $h(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ by assumptions. Finally, you can use Boltzano's theorem to say there is some $c$ belonging to that interval such that

$$h(c)=0$$